# FragmentManager incompatible types for support libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

Get a constant error for the FragmentManager of incompatible types. Need the support libraries for it to work, but cannot figure it out. Android Studio says that it requires the support import, which is there, but finds the androidx import.

````
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class CrimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crime);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);

        if(fragment == null)
        {
            fragment = new CrimeFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();


        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: If you're using androidx, everything should be coming from `androidx`, rather than `android.support`. What exactly do you mean by " Android Studio says that it requires the support import"? What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: "Incompatible Types
required: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
found: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager"

Comment: Yeah, change those two `android.support` imports to `androidx`. If you just delete them, your IDE should prompt you to select the correct ones.

Comment: Yeah, as it turns out it works. Apparently the support libraries are pointless now.

Comment: They basically just turned into androidx at version 28. Most everything works about the same, though, taking into account all of the inevitable upgrades and changes that have happened since the switch-over.

Comment: Thanks man, it's been making me insane.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, if you're new, and starting fresh projects, you should really only have to use androidx. You would only need to worry about the old support libraries if you're supporting an old app, or when you have to translate old examples to use the new classes. [This page of class mappings](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings) might be of some help with that, if you ever hit one that your IDE won't do automatically. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, change those two android.support imports to androidx. If you just delete them, your IDE should prompt you to select the correct ones. – Mike M. https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m